# Picasso doesn't load image from the sd card

Tags: android, picasso, android-gallery

I am using Gallery to choose photo in our application then using the Picasso to load the image

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),MobileConstant.newInstance().REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```

When I use the Picasso to load the image from the path return from the above code, I can't load the image if the file was stored in sdcard but it show the one in local.

I have the permission set :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Check your Uri that it is not null .if it not null then check it's getPath() value.

Comment: I can see the path return as content://media/external/images/media/60827

Comment: Are you using the latest Picasso version?